# Divs inside of wrapper div are not aligning properly

Tags: html, css

I need to know why I cannot get my sidebar inside of my wrapper div to stay on the right and my main_content div to stay on the left side of my wrapper.
I would like the following model:

```
       WRAPPER DIV:
   ______________________________
  {                   /  sidebar }
  {                   /   div    }
  {      m_c div      /          }
  {                   /          }
  { __________________/__________}
```

1) What code am I missing that does not let me align the divs inside of the wrapper?

2) Also, I drew a border around each div so that I can visualize them with ease; now why is my main_content div disappear whenever it comes across text? If you run it in fiddle you can see what i'm talking about. There are holes in the border near the text; how can I make that disappear?

Thank you.

```css
/*Comment example - created 10/12/16*/

* {
  font-family: 'Libre Franklin', sans-serif;
  background-color: rgb(155, 155, 155);
}

.wrapper { /*black*/
  width:960px;
  min-height: 700px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
  margin: 0 auto;
  display:inline-block;
}

.main_content{ /*Green*/
  width: 730px;
  min-height: inherit;
  border: 2px solid rgb(222, 26, 26);
  float:left;

}

.sidebar_one{ /*White*/
  width: 230px;
  min-height:inherit;
  border: 1px solid rgb(255,255,255);
  float:right;
  position:absolute;
  color:rgb(242, 70, 16);
  overflow:hidden;
}

h2 {
  position:relative;
  left:5px;
}

h5 {
  position:relative;
  left:5px;
}

p {
  position:relative;
  left:5px;
}
```

```html
   

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--Created 10/12/16  ///// ideas: emrisk-->
<html>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Franklin" rel="stylesheet">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
    <!--Added external Stylesheet-->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <!--Added external javascript file-->
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="main_content">
        <h2>TEST </h2>
        <!-- END OF H2 -->
        <h5>random test standard of web-based and cloud-based server systems since 2007.
                           </h5>
        <!-- END OF H5 -->
        <p>
          Our clients have trusted our team for almost a decade and throughout the years we have proven our worth over and over again.
        </p>
        <!-- END OF P -->
      </div>
      <!-- END OF MAIN_CONTENT -->
      <div class="sidebar_one">
        Test
      </div>
      <!-- END OF SIDEBAR_ONE -->
    </div>
    <!-- END OF wrapper -->

  </body>

</html>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove position:absolute from below and decrease the width of sidebar_one:-

```
.sidebar_one{ /*White*/
  width: 210px;
  min-height:inherit;
  border: 1px solid rgb(255,255,255);
  float:right;

  color:rgb(242, 70, 16);
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked! I learned that you should actually have some pixels left over; my problem was that I was making exact calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Try [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).  There's an awesome tool for discovering how it works [here](http://bennettfeely.com/flexplorer/), and it completely eliminates the nastiness that is involved in CSS layout.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!